# В переменную int некорректно записывается произведение двух больших чисел

Tags: c++, типы-данных, арифметика

```
long long int var=100000*100000;
```

В var оказывается 1410065408, хотя 100000^2=10 000 000 000. Почему так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что числа - `int`, умножаются, как `int`, и дают в результате `int` с урезанным переполнением: 10000000000 в шестнадцатеричной записи - 2540BE400. Обрезая до 4 байт, имеем 540BE400, или 1410065408.

Попробуйте явно указать, что вы умножаете `long long`'и - не пожалеете :)

```
long long int var=100000ll*100000ll;
```

Comment: Не пожалеете!!! Еххх, весело сказано...

Comment: Ну, или  же  (long long)100000*100000

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну, это все равно что `100000ll*100000;` :)

Comment: Harry, думаю что  сойдет и так. В чем я не прав?... С таким вариантом точно не будут умножаться как int

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Нет, вы совершенно правы. Я только хотел сказать, что ` (long long)100000` - это то же самое, что и `100000ll`.

Comment: " и дают в результате int с урезанным переполнением..." вообще-то это не так. Во всяком случае такой ответ вводит в заблуждение

Comment: @Slava 10000000000 в шестнадцатеричной записи - 2540BE400. Обрезая до 4 байт, имеем 540BE400, или 1410065408. Объясните это иначе, не вводя в заблуждение. Я сделал это как мог проще и понятнее, очередь за вами :)

Comment: @Harry переполнение для знаковых целых - UB.  Поэтому "обрезая до 4 байт"  - это и есть ввести в заблуждение. Детали можно найти здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c

Comment: @Slava Этот вопрос уже неоднократно обсуждался. Да, формально - UB. Но покажите хоть один компилятор, который поступит иначе :) Или вы *в своем ответе* объясните, что 1410065408 - случайность? :) Знаете этот анекдот про воздушный шар и математика? Так вот, вам никто не мешает давать здесь абсолютно точные ответы...

Comment: @Harry видите ли, ваши ответы читают начинающие программисты, и у них запросто отложится, что такое поведение валидно. И они запросто смогут написать такой код `int a = ...; if( a + 100 < 0 ) // переполнение` потому что вы ему рассказали, что обрезая. Надеюсь не нужно рассказывать, чем чреват такой код?

Comment: @Harry "Или вы в своем ответе объясните, что 1410065408 - случайность?" к сожалению у UB есть одно паршивое свойство - иногда программа ведет себя так, как ожидается. Да случайность. Никто не гарантирует, что завтра не перестанет работать.

Answer (score 3):

В таких ситуациях для избежания переполнения и обеспечения типонезависимости кода можно порекомендовать реализовывать операцию умножения в два этапа

```
long long int var = 100000;
var *= 100000;
```

Это позволить вам избежать ненужного повторения явной типизации, т.е. явной привязки ваших констант к конкретным типам.

Альтернативным вариантом, уместным в некоторых контекстах, будет перенести явную типизацию в правую часть

```
auto var = 100000ll * 100000;
```